# Error while compiling programs - Ubuntu Mate

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ubuntu

I do compile few programs with no error at Raspbian OS but Today I want to try same programs on Ubuntu Mate. I keep getting same error.

Code is

```
git clone -b r606 https://github.com/vthoang/cgminer.git
cd cgminer
CFLAGS="-O2 -march=native" ./autogen.sh --enable-gekko
make -j 2
```

Which returns

```
/usr/include/netdb.h:32:11: fatal error: rpc/netdb.h: No such file or directory
```

During compiling. Not sure why its happening.

Comment: Looks like basic error of missing dev files. try to install `netdb-dev` or something like this before compilation.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libjnr-netdb-java`, that might fix your problem.